# where the PCA and eigenfaces enter this code?

Tags: opencv, pca

MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetected = gray.DetectHaarCascade(
                  face,
                  1.2,
                  10,
                  Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                  new Size(20, 20));

```
                //Action for each element detected
                foreach (MCvAvgComp f in facesDetected[0])
                {
                    t = t + 1;
                    result = currentFrame.Copy(f.rect).Convert<gray,>().Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
                    //draw the face detected in the 0th (gray) channel with blue color
                    currentFrame.Draw(f.rect, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);


                    if (trainingImages.ToArray().Length != 0)
                    {
                        //TermCriteria for face recognition with numbers of trained images like maxIteration
                    MCvTermCriteria termCrit = new MCvTermCriteria(ContTrain, 0.001);

                    //Eigen face recognizer
                    EigenObjectRecognizer recognizer = new EigenObjectRecognizer(
                       trainingImages.ToArray(),
                       labels.ToArray(),
                       5000,
                       ref termCrit);

                    name = recognizer.Recognize(result);

                        //Draw the label for each face detected and recognized
                    currentFrame.Draw(name, ref font, new Point(f.rect.X - 2, f.rect.Y - 2), new Bgr(Color.LightGreen));

                    }
```

}

Comment: If do not know this is not C, don't add the tag!

Comment: Do tell! So you added the "C" tag, because the source code resides on partition `C:`, I guess.

Comment: kkkkk.The programming language is C #

Comment: Last comment on that nonsense (I type very slowly, prhaps that helps): A matching first letter of a name does not imply identity, **Dimitry**!